# i am getting same error 'module datetime has no attribute date', for all problems in pandas python program

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

program:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series({'a' : 'm',

'a' : 's',

's' : 'su'})

print(a)
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "ami.py", line 1, in <module>

    import pandas as pd

  File "C:\Users\Amit Mozar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>

__import__(dependency)

  File "C:\Users\Amit Mozar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytz\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>

import datetime

File "C:\Users\Amit Mozar\Desktop\python\datetime.py", line 1, in <module>

   import calendar

  File "C:\Users\Amit Mozar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\calendar.py", line 50, in <module>

    class _localized_month:

  File "C:\Users\Amit Mozar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\calendar.py", line 52, in _localized_month

    _months = [datetime.date(2001, i+1, 1).strftime for i in range(12)]

  File "C:\Users\Amit Mozar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\calendar.py", line 52, in <listcomp>

    _months = [datetime.date(2001, i+1, 1).strftime for i in range(12)]

AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date'
```

Answer (score 0):

please import it like this `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: i think its not datetime issues , can you please uninstall and reinstall pandas